# dpm() does not display any results on screen

Tags: 7, debugging

I have the same problem as [file_scan_directory() takes about 10 seconds to execute](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24087/file-scan-directory-takes-about-10-seconds-to-execute/). I just tried the `dpm(func_get_args())` suggestion, and unfortunately it doesn't show anything to me.

I've cleared all the caches, and run the cron tasks. What am I missing?

Comment: make sure you have permissions to _Access Developer Information_ under devel in people/permissions

Answer (score 30):

Make sure you have `print $messages;` in your `page.tpl.php`template file. By default, devel (dpm) is configured to print it's content in the message area of the site. So if your template for some reason does not render the contents of `$messages`, you won't see anything.

Answer (score 16):

1. Sometimes `krumo($variable)` might work when `dpm($variable)` doesn't.
2. Sometimes `print dpm($variable)` might work when `dpm($variable)` doesn't.
3. 2. might also be the solution when there's no `print $messages` in your `page.tpl.php` anymore. Maybe you can add it back.

Answer (score 10):

You must be logged-in to the Drupal site, with the correct permissions to access Devel. Log in as admin should do it.

Comment: Being logged-in is not necessary, if the anonymous users have the right permission.

Comment: This permission can be found at 'admin/people/permissions' under 'Access developer information.'

Answer (score 9):

I'd highly recommend [devel_debug_log](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_debug_log). It requires the devel module, and it gives you the ddl() function. ddl adds a page to your reports in configuration, so it's similar to printing to watchdog, but you have a nice clean page where you can send your debug messages, and not worry about race-type conditions where your messages might get cleared before you have a chance to see them--or, as in your case, theme issues.

(This is also an EXTREMELY useful tool if you're trying to build out any sort of API, as all those requests would never show you any kind of dpm() messages.)

Comment: This was the best overall solution for me.

Comment: Also invaluable when debugging ajax requests.

Answer (score 7):

Ensure that you have enabled and installed the [Devel](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module as `dpm()` is a function declared in this module.

`dpm()` description taken from [here](https://ratatosk.backpackit.com/pub/1836982-debugging-drupal).

> Prints a variable to the ‘message’ area of the page using
>   drupal_set_message(). You can use this function to keep track of one
>   or more variables when you’re working on the code running your site.
>   Because the Devel module now comes with Krumo, the output is compact
>   and unobtrusive.
>
> `dpm($input, $name = NULL)`
>
> If, for some reason, you are not using Krumo, you can use the $name
>   parameter to distinguish between different calls to dpm().

After you have downloaded and enabled Devel, try the answer from [file_scan_directory() takes about 10 seconds to execute](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24087/file-scan-directory-takes-about-10-seconds-to-execute/) again and it should work.

Comment: It remains the same. I installed and enabled devel module, cleared all caches, run cron and still dpm(func_get_args()) doesn't show anything.

Comment: Where are you putting `dpm(func_get_args());`?

Comment: In bootstrap.inc file: 
dpm(func_get_args());
$matches = drupal_system_listing("/^" . DRUPAL_PHP_FUNCTION_PATTERN . "\.$extension$/", $dir, 'name', 0); 
...

Comment: Try changing `dpm(func_get_args());` to `die(print_r(func_get_args());` - bypass Devel for the moment.

Comment: It didn't change anything either.

Comment: Have you run [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) and got report details from that as per the other question.  Your poor performance may be down to something else if this isn't working.

Comment: If the second command recommened by Chapabu doesn't change anything, then it simply means that the code is not called and you aren't affected by the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to print it from inside a function without touching (or having) a template file, try this:

```
$nid = 3;
$node = node_load($nid);
dpm($node);
print theme('status_messages');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is sometimes a result of a resource on the page returning a 404.

Drupal renders the 404 page and in doing so fetches (and clears) the messages from the session and puts them on the 404 page that you don't see. Then when the main page fetches the messages there are none left.

You can open the network tab and check to see if any resources have a 404 status.

An easy solution here is to enable fast 404 by uncommenting this line in settings.php:

```
# drupal_fast_404();
```

Another good solution here is to use [devel_debug_log](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_debug_log) as suggested by SlakeFistcrunch.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the message can be cut or won't work in case of AJAX.

More reliable method is to do just (then remove after finish):

```
var_dump($data); die();
```

Or you can use [`dd()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7.x-1.x) (part of Devel as well), e.g.

```
dd(func_get_args());
```

then check your log file (in temp folder), e.g.

```
$ tail -f /tmp/drupal_debug.txt
```

Using above method is more convenient, quicker and it may support AJAX or other request without breaking the current site rendering.

---

If you still like `dpm()`, try also using `kint()` (enable the included Kint submodule for these pretty print of variables).

Answer (score 1):

If only some `dpm()` calls do not work, it can be due to `dpm()` crashing. I saw it happening in the following scenario in a custom form submit handler:

```
function mymodule_formid_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form_state);
}
```

I believe the error condition was caught by an exception handler in `dpm()`, because the page was displaying fine, no WSOD or something, just no `dpm()` message either. The error is probably undetected recursion, because using [`ddl($form_state)`](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_debug_log) instead resulted in browser maxing out on memory when watching the corresponding object in the report generated by the Devel Debug Log module.

As a workaround, try to print only a (relevant) part of the object, like `dpm($form_state['values'])` or `dpm(array_keys($form_state))`.

Answer (score 0):

For **Drupal 8**

Make sure status_messages is an **enabled** block in `/admin/structure/block` and inside a used region of your theme

[image]

And depending on your theme's setup you might have to actually print it manually inside your `page.html.twig` template

```
{{ page.status_messages }}
```