# alterations in tpl file work, but not dpm();, dsm(); or drupal_set_message();

Tags: 7, theming, debugging

[This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24217/dpm-does-not-display-any-results-on-screen) here at DA has a popular suggestion to check `page.tpl.php` to see if it says `print $messages;`. I verified this and this is the case.

I cleared caches many times, btw after which there actually is a drupal message saying the caches are cleared.

I made sure the `dpm()`, `dsm()` or `drupal_set_message()` functions are nicely outside any conditional statement or php logic whatsoever. I also put all these functions on different places in the `tpl` file. Still no result.

The same theme also has another tpl file that I used before and had some commented dpm(); functions that I uncommented but these didn't work anymore either.

Devel module is **enabled** and I am logged in as **admin** the whole time.

Comment: I *think* what you are experiencing is a timing issue for no better explanation.  If you look in `includes/bootstrap.inc` you will see that all the various message functions populate or look at a session variable with or for the contents of the message.  These are then plucked via process_page() in `includes/theme.inc` which populates the `$messages` variable.  So, if you are calling these functions INSIDE the page template, this variable has already been set, so these new messages are either lost or should/will eventually appear when a subsequent page is loaded...

Comment: @Jimajamma is what you are suggesting still that the cause of my problem has much if not everything to do with the fact that I am trying to use, `dpm();`, `dsm();`, and *even* `drupal_set_message();` from a `tpl` file? I mean, for all anyone should care for in this purpose, my end goal could be that I just want to output a hardcoded string with `drupal_set_message();`. If you catch my drift.

Comment: without seeing what exactly you are doing in your template, that's most probably correct.  but since, once again, Drupal puts all of the output of these in `$messages` before the template it processed, using them inside the template will either, once again, not work, or will be delayed until a subsequent page load.  So, if within a template, you want to have further messages displayed, you could add in logic that appends information to the `$messages` variable and then they would show up when it is printed, or you could do any other php coding, eg a direct print of a message yourself, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpm() does not display any results on screen](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24217/dpm-does-not-display-any-results-on-screen)

Comment: It's left unclear in your question if you also went through all other answers in the mentioned question, so I'm marking yours as possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You have access to the entire Drupal bootstrap within template files. Template files are loading at the very end of a page request post bootstrap. If dpm() or dpr() is not working it is most likely because you are viewing the site as an anonymous user. The devel module by default does not allow access to it's functionality for anonymous users. Try logging in as admin and you should see the output of your devel module function calls.

As an F.Y.I. template files are not the typical place for a dpm() as you either need to know the variable you are after or put a get_defined_vars() calls inside it which can be quite heavy depending on where you are in stack. It is more common to use dpm()'s in template hooks such as:

- [template_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7)
- [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7)

  function template_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    dpm($vars);
  }

Then you can see all the variables that are available to your template files.

Comment: I should have mentioned I was logged in as admin the whole time(I do now). That said, It shouldn't matter if templates are not a typical place for `dpm();` functions. It's besides the point. The problem is I can't even use `drupal_set_message();`. What I want to output in these functions is besides the point too.

Comment: If that is the case I would suggest checking your Drupal log. There is an off chance errors are being thrown but they are not being displayed because drupal_set_message() is not working.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I noticed that even my database logging module was disabled. Enabled it off course. Also error logging was also set to 'none', which could have been a good candidate for a solution. So I also set this to 'display all'. Still though, no drupal_set_message(); results after setting both of these things straight. At the same time, if you take into consideration that the message 'Every cache cleared' actually *does* get output every time I clear the caches, the idea that something is holding back the messaging alltogether becomes less interesting don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix for your issue but a work around could be to use [Devel Debug Log](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_debug_log) instead. You can use ddl($var) and will save to a log in which you can see the output on the log page. Much better than trying to spit out dpm messages in $messages variable.